# Is a lock on an integer required in this case?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I have a "unique" type integer. I use it like this:

```
int unique=0;
public int GetUniqueId()
{
  return unique++;
}
```

I know I'm being a bit paranoid, but is this an atomic operation, or would it require some form of lock? This function will be used in a extremely concurrent class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No; this is emphatically *not* atomic.
`x++` compiles to three separate instructions (load, increment, store), which can be interrupted by other threads.

If this will run on multiple threads, you should call `Interlocked.Increment(ref unique)` (which is atomic) instead.
This call is somewhat slower than a regular increment, much much faster than a full lock.

Comment: And it's things like this that make writing concurrent code extremely scary :)

Comment: I thought the x86 instruction set's inc was atomic if memory was aligned?

Comment: @ta.speot.is that may be true, but I do know there isn't an atomic `inc` instruction in IL now... So, it may be atomic under x86 in certain JIT compilers, but not guaranteed to be so..

Comment: @ta.speot.is This question indicates that the INC instruction is not atomic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109679/how-come-inc-instruction-of-x86-is-not-atomic

Answer (score 0):

If this method is used by the concurrent threads then you have to handle the concurrency which is achieved by putting the lock.