# How is it possible for some threads to never execute?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

```
int x = 0 // global shared variable
T1: for (i=0; i++; i<100) x++;
T2: x++ // no loop, just one increment
```

T1 and T2 are separate threads. I am told the final value of x can be ANYTHING from the values of 1 and 101. How is this possible? I am wondering how this could possibly just be 1.

Obviously, something fails in the execution sequence, but I'm wondering what.

Comment: what language is it?

Comment: Assuming an arbitrary language

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`x++` is not atomic operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109679/how-come-inc-instruction-of-x86-is-not-atomic) (at least in most languages), this operation actually works like this:

```
tmp = x;
tmp = tmp + 1;
x = tmp;
```

now assume next execution order:

```
T2: tmp = x; // tmp is 0
T1: run all loop iterations, finally x is 100
T2: tmp = tmp+1; x = tmp; // x is 1
```

to get any other number, imagine next order:

```
T1: started loop, at some point x is 45
T2: tmp = x; // tmp is 45
T1: finished loop, x is 100
T2: tmp = tmp+1; x = tmp; // x is 46
```

Comment: Thanks! So, how is it possible to end at some number, say 46?

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The reason for this behavior is memory caching.</strike>  Since threads can be executed on independent cpu's following situation is possible:

T1: loads x value
T2: loads x value
T1: runs loop 10 times (T1_x=10)
T2: increments (T2_x=1)
T1: saves value 10 to memory
T2: saves value 1 to memory

This is why you need thread synchronization. You can read more here: [Mutex example / tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989451/mutex-example-tutorial)

Thank you @Lashane for correction.

Comment: what is memory caching?

Comment: CPU has a very fast built in memory called cache. Each modern CPU used in a PC has it. Take [Intel web page](http://ark.intel.com/products/family/75023/4th-Generation-Intel-Core-i7-Processors#@All) as an example. You can find more info here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache

Comment: you want to say - that for CPUs without cache - we will not be able to get 1?

Comment: before answer please read [how cpu cache actually works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) and why it is not the case here

Comment: even for single cpu - situation with 1 at the end is possible

Comment: Dear @Lashane, I agree - the reason for this behavior is thread preemption. But can you explain the low level mechanics of the tmp variable from your example? I think we both agree, that one of possibilities is that the value is stored in CPU register, when context is switched. Is this the only possible reason for tmp existence?

Comment: for low level - right, tmp variable can be well known register (like ax/eax for x86), also some [risc cpus does not control pipeline execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining#Workarounds) (it is up to developer/compiler), for high-level - java works as stack machine, so it could "pop" old value before any modifications by other thread and store it in ordinary ram